# Is it possible to create a required class as nested class in less?

Tags: css, less

Is it possible to write a nested version of

```
.foo.bar
```

in less? Like

```
.foo {
    .bar { } // ='nested'; creates '.foo .bar' tho
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can reference the parent selector by using the [`&` operator](http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature).

```
.foo {
  &.bar {
    color: #f00;
  }
}
```

Which compiles to:

```
.foo.bar {
  color: #f00;
}
```

Comment: Well that makes sense. Thanks